# Attaching Entities when using ObjectContext having lifetime of Http Request

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using .NET 3.5 SP1 in ASP.NET MVC application.

While using ObjectContext with Http Request lifetime, and trying to attach an entity ALREADY present in context, we get error:
*"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."*
For Example, the code :

```
Category newCategory = new Category {CategoryId = CategoryIdSelected};
ctx.AttachTo("CategorySet", newCategory);
```

will give error if 'Category' with CategoryId = CategoryIdSelected exists in ObjectContext.

Modified code to check for existing entity:

```
Category newCategory = new Category {CategoryId = CategoryIdSelected};
ObjectStateEntry stateEntry = null;

if( ctx.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(newCategory, out stateEntry)){
   //EntityObject already attached in context, get it
    newCategory = (EntityObject)stateEntry.Entity;
}else{
    ctx.AttachTo("CategorySet", newCategory);   
}
```

The modified code is still giving same error:
*"[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."*

Please advise ?

Thank You

---

**QUESTION ADDENDUM:**

More problems attaching Entities when using ObjectContext having lifetime of Http Request.

For Example, if we have 'AppUser','Category' and Department entities.

```
public class AppUser : System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject{   
 public int Uid {get; set;}   
 public string UserName {get; set;}   
 public string Password {get; set;}   
 public Department Dept {get; set;}   
 public Category catg {get; set;}
 ...........   
}
```

AppUser has relationship with Department and Category Entities.
Now when trying to attach 'user':

```
user = new AppUser{Uid=1,catg = new Category {categoryId=10}, Dept = new Department{departmentId=101}, ...}
var key = ctx.CreateEntityKey("AppUserSet", user);
if (ctx.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(key, out stateEntry)) {
```

will work ONLY if, in context :

- there is NO Category with categoryId=10, and
- there is NO Department with departmentId=101

One option, is to ensure context does not have attached entities by always retrieving using NOMERGE NoTracking option. BUT I found following problems with MergeOption.NoTracking:

- Second call would still result in db hit
- You don't get EntityKeys on EntityRefs. So EntityKey of XXXReference is null,which means NO FK Stub. [Please see](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/7492f76f-7e04-46da-a54d-26c06f1872a1).
  **How to get EntityKey of Reference w/o loading both ends (both entities)?**
- Even though Entity are Detached, they have a reference to the DataContext (via entity._realtionships._context).  [Please see.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=507482)

**Please advise.**

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using two different contexts. You check one, and then attach to the other:

```
if( csContext. //...){
   ///
}else{
    ctx. // ...
}
```

The entity appears to be in `ctx`, but not in `csContext`. My advice is to use only one context at a time whenever possible; it's much less confusing.

**Update**

OK, you've changed the code in your question.

My guess is that your stub object doesn't have an EntityKey, so TryGetObjectStateEntry is returning false. Try:

```
if( ctx.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(
    new EntityKey("MyEntities.CategorySet", "CategoryId", CategoryIdSelected), 
    out stateEntry)){
```

Obviously, replace "MyEntities" with the actual model name.